CORS causing my file upload to fail in a kubernetes application with fastAPI and React frontend
I have been trying to get my frontend to work with a fastAPI to upload a file to a database. I keep hitting the CORS issue, have gone through multiple stackoverflow threads but Im still not any closer to a solution.
Here is my fastAPI code:
from fastapi import (
    APIRouter,
    Depends,
    HTTPException,
    UploadFile,
    File
)
from fastapi import FastAPI, File, UploadFile
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
import httpx

app = FastAPI()

# Add CORS middleware to the app (not to the router)
app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=["*"],  # Allows all origins
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],  # Allows all methods
    allow_headers=["*"],  # Allows all headers
)

router = APIRouter(
    prefix="/api",
    tags=["api"],
    responses={404: {"description": "404 Page Not Found"}},
)

@router.get("/")
async def read_items():
    return "<h1>Page</h1>"


@router.post("/upload")
async def upload(file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    print("Upload")

app.include_router(router)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import uvicorn
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=20000)


Here is the code for the fastAPI pod:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: api-deployment
  labels:
    app: api
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: api
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: api
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: api
        image: api:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Never
        ports:
        - containerPort: 12980
          name: web

Here is the api-service:
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: api-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: api
  ports:
    - name: http
      protocol: TCP
      port: 20000
      targetPort: 20000

The nginx proxy default.conf (I am not yet proxying the calls because I want to see if the preflight check passes first):
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name api.localhost;

   add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' $http_origin;
   add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
   add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Authorization,Accept,Origin,DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range';
   add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET,POST,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE,PATCH';

  location / {

     if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
      add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
      add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
      add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' $http_origin;
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Authorization,Accept,Origin,DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range';
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET,POST,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE,PATCH';
    }

    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-real-ip $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-forward-for $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    #   proxy_pass http://cos-service.default.svc.cluster.local:20000/;
  }
}


I build this nginx conf into a docker image called nginx-cors.
And this is the deployment file for nginx:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-cors
  labels:
    app: nginx-cors
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx-cors
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx-cors
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx-cors
        image: nginx-cors:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Never
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: nginx

with its own service:
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-svc
spec:
  selector:
    app: nginx-cors
  ports:
    - name: http
      protocol: TCP
      port: 11999
      targetPort: 80

And finally, the React code for accessing this:
import React, { useState, ChangeEvent, FormEvent } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const FileUpload: React.FC = () => {
  const [selectedFile, setSelectedFile] = useState<File | null>(null);
  const [uploadProgress, setUploadProgress] = useState<number>(0);

  const handleFileChange = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    if (event.target.files && event.target.files.length > 0) {
      setSelectedFile(event.target.files[0]);
    }
  };

  const handleUpload = async (event: FormEvent) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    if (!selectedFile) {
      alert('Please select a file first');
      return;
    }

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', selectedFile);
    console.log("formdata ", formData);

    try {
      const response = await axios.post('http://nginx-svc:11999/', formData, {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        },
        onUploadProgress: (progressEvent) => {
          const percentCompleted = Math.round((progressEvent.loaded * 100) / progressEvent.total);
          setUploadProgress(percentCompleted);
        },
      });
      if (response.status === 201) {
        alert('File uploaded successfully');
      } else {
        alert('File upload failed');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error uploading file:', error);
      alert('Error uploading file');
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleUpload}>
        <input type="file" onChange={handleFileChange} />
        <button type="submit">Upload File</button>
      </form>
      {uploadProgress > 0 && <p>Upload Progress: {uploadProgress}%</p>}
    </div>
  );
};

export default FileUpload;


When I click the upload button in the browser, it fails with:



and the network debug on my firefox-esr shows the following:



and



Could someone please tell me what's going wrong?

This is a side note: never just replay the origin back to the client without validating that it's one of the expected values; if you don't, you've essentially just disabled the same origin policy (meaning that any website can make requests to your endpoint, and in the case of cookies, on behalf of your user). Also, the response headers from nginx are important to debug this further.

@MatsLindh, thank you. Are you referring to add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' $http_origin ? Also, where can I find the response headers from nginx? I am unable to get them from the Response tab -its empty. It says: Response is not available to scripts (Reason: CORS failed).

You can copy the request as a curl request and then run it through curl if you're unable to inspect the response from the OPTIONS request.
